# SQL Server Windows authentication - username not changed

Tags: sql-server

I've recently changed my PC name and Windows user account as well.

Before: `OLDPCNAME\oldusername`

After: `NEWPCNAME\newusername`

When I log in to my SQL Server management studio using Windows Authentication, it populates the User Name field with `NEWPCNAME\oldusername`. I have no problems logging in whatsoever. How can I change this such that my new username is used?

**EDIT:**

I'm using different versions of SQL Server. All have the same issue

- SQL Server 2008
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server 2014 R2

**OS:** Windows 10

**Management Studio:** SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: Try using runas /user:NEWPCNAME\newusername ssms.exe. If you still have the same problem, then you need to delete a cached connection.